# What is the correct sentence structure in pinyin?

Tags: sentence-structure, pinyin

I'm a little confused wrt to the basic sentence structure:
Is "Nimen he shenme?" correct. Also can someone point out what is the basic structure for sentences and questions as in: Subject + Verb + object.

Pardon me, i'm a beginner in Pinyin

Comment: ✓ cf。iciba fanyi：你们喝什么 What do you drink？

Comment: Solely using pinyin, particularly without tone marks, makes it difficult for people to know what you're trying to say. Do you know what characters you're supposed to be using, or what the meaning of the intended phrase is? Moreover, there's no such thing as "correct sentence structure" in _pinyin_: pinyin is not a language; it is merely a system used to romanise Chinese characters.

Comment: It sounds like something like the Chinese Grammar Wiki would be good for you: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/

Comment: I've never seen people writing in PinYin. PinYin is not a separate language, it is only for representing Chinese characters in a Romanized form. So you should be looking for the grammar for Standard Chinese or Written Vernacular Chinese.

Comment: I guess you're asking "where to break a sentence written in pinyin" – either way, please edit and elaborate the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

To a native speaker, even the phrase "he shenme nimen?" makes sense, but I would say the general structure to what you are trying to say is:

**Subj. + Verb + 什么(What) + Sometimes optional(Noun) ?**

Example 1: 你(You) + 喝(Drink) + 什么(What)? In this case, you don't need to follow by a noun, because "drink" is normally water/soft drink/alchol

Example 2: 你(You) + 用(Use) + 什么(What) + 手机(Phone)? In this case, you are asking specifically what phone they are using.

For an in depth explanation, please have a look at this link, it has plenty of structures and usages:

[Placement of question words](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Placement_of_question_words)

Answer (score 0):

Sentence structure does not change based on whether you use pinyin or characters.

The basic sentence structure is subject-verb-object, with any attributes going before the corresponding sentence part:

> Kouke de nimen man-man de he dian shenme?
>   *The thirsty you slowly drink a
>   bit of what?*
>   adjective-subject adverb-verb adjective-object

There are exceptions, some types of sentences are formed differently. But as a beginner, you'll be OK with S-V-O almost all the time.